# Is there a regex to match a float with at most 7 digits?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex to match a float with at most 7 digits. I cant figure out how to handle the decimal point in this. Is it even possible to match this with a regex? There has to be atleast 1 digit to the left of the decimal, and 0-6 digits to the right, but the total number of digits has to be 7 or less.

examples:

Good:

- 1.234567
- 0.1
- 1234567
- 1

Bad:

- .1234567
- 12345678
- 1.2.34567

Comment: Why not convert to a string (unless you're using a language where this step is unnecessary), take out the decimal point, and then count the digits remaining?

Comment: Do you need to support "+/-" prefixes or "e" notation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work:

```
^(?!.*\..*\.|\d{8})\d[\d.]{,7}$
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/gglVngm0pH

Explanation:

```
^            # beginning of string anchor
(?!          # start negative lookahead (fail if following regex can match)
   .*\..*\.    # two or more '.' characters exist in the string
   |           # OR
   \d{8}       # eight consecutive digits in the string
)            # end negative lookahead
\d           # match a digit
[\d.]{,7}    # match between 0 and 7 characters that are either '.' or a digit
$            # end of string anchor
```

Comment: Interesting logic but IMO overcomplicated. First, backtracking-wise the `.*` would be more efficient as `[^.]*`. But I would just go for `^(?=(?:\D*\d){1,7}$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` which is more direct.